# UIView drawing inside UITableViewCell not appearing

Tags: uitableview, uiview

I am using PaintCode to add some images to UITableViewCell and the PaintCode images (being drawn within a `UIView`) are not reliably showing up on screen.

There is a horizontal stack view that contains 3 horizontal stack views, some of which may be hidden depending on the model. If one of the inner stack views is potentially set to `hidden=YES` then the `UIView` within that stack view won't always show up, even though the view is there and the stack view is making room for it.

It's probably easier to just show you:

[image: xcode view inspector]

As you can see in the View Hierarchy inspector screenshot, there is room next to the 4 for a maroon hexagon, but it doesn't show up. If I select the cell, you can always see the hexagon while the cell is highlighted, and then if I push and pop new view controllers onto the stack, sometimes the hexagon will remain (as in the cell below). The hexagon is almost always missing on initial load of the tableview though. The `.hidden` property is never directly accessed on the `UIView` itself, only on the containing `UIStackView`.

The code for controlling loading the UITabelViewCell is below (the `debtStack` contains the hexagon in question):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CardCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CardCustomCell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CardCustomCell"];
}

[cell cellCard:self.rowArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]];
cell.cellButton.hidden = YES;

return cell;
```

}

```
- (void)cellCard:(Card *)card {

if ([[BlackListSingleton theBlackList] cardExists:card]) {
    [self setBadge:1];
} else if ([[WhiteListSingleton theWhiteList] cardExists:card]) {
    [self setBadge:2];
} else {
    [self setBadge:0];
}

self.typeLabel.text = [Card stringForCardType:card.cardType];
self.nameLabel.text = card.cardName;

if (card.coinCost) {
    self.coinStack.hidden = NO;
    self.coinCost.text = card.coinCost;
} else {
    self.coinStack.hidden = YES;
}
if (card.potionCost) {
    self.potionStack.hidden = NO;
    self.potionCost.text = card.potionCost;
} else {
    self.potionStack.hidden = YES;
}
if (card.debtCost) {
    self.debtStack.hidden = NO;
    self.debtCost.text = card.debtCost;
} else {
    self.debtStack.hidden = YES;
}

[self cardTypeImage:card.cardType];
```

}

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue hoki

Comment: @Tom Sadly no (it even reared it's head in another app I maintain. In the end I had to switch out the code-drawn images for actual png's.

Comment: I managed to get this working a few hours after I posted this comment. If your still interested I'll share the code with you when I'm next at the pc

Comment: @Tom - Yes, I'm am extremely interested. Would love to go back to code drawing and reduce the size of my app bundle. Also I'm legitimately curious about what the deal was.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is not the most elegant solution. You could improve this answer by adding the drawing methods to an array and call as required but this is my first iteration on how I resolved this issue.

So first of all we create a prototype cell in storyboard, subclass your uitableviewcell / collectionviewcell ensuring you remember to add the class in your identity inspector.

my uitableviewcell subclass looks like this

```
import UIKit

class CategoriesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryView: DesignIconView!
    @IBOutlet weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    let cView = DesignIconView()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)


    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func configure(forRow row : Int, title : String, subTitle: String){

        cView.drawForRow = row
        cView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: categoryView.frame.width, height: categoryView.frame.height)
        cView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        categoryView.addSubview(cView)

        titleLabel.text  = title
        subtitleLabel.text = subTitle

    }



}
```

Next I added a view to the prototype cell, created a uiview subclass and set the class again in the identity inspector

my uiview subclass looks like this.. again you can easily improve this by adding the drawing methods to an array, but for simplicity ill use a switch statement.

```
import UIKit

class DesignIconView: UIView {

    private var _drawForRow : Int!

    var drawForRow: Int! {
        set {

            _drawForRow = newValue
        } get {

            if _drawForRow == nil {
                _drawForRow = 0
            }
           return _drawForRow
        }
    }

    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code

        guard  _drawForRow != nil else {
            return _drawForRow = 0
        }
        // marketing, business, lifestyle, music, tech, video, design
        switch _drawForRow {
        case 0:
            CategoryIcons.drawMarketingIcon(frame: self.bounds, resizing: .aspectFit)
        case 1:
            CategoryIcons.drawBusinessIcon(frame: self.bounds, resizing: .aspectFit)
        case 2:
            CategoryIcons.drawLifeStyleIcon(frame: self.bounds, resizing: .aspectFit)
        case 3:
            CategoryIcons.drawMusicIcon(frame: self.bounds, resizing: .aspectFit)
        case 4:
            CategoryIcons.drawTechIcon(frame: self.bounds, resizing: .aspectFit)
        case 5:
            CategoryIcons.drawVideoIcon(frame: self.bounds, resizing: .aspectFit)
        case 6:
            CategoryIcons.drawDesignIcon(frame: self.bounds, resizing: .aspectFit)


        default:
            CategoryIcons.drawMusicIcon(frame: self.bounds, resizing: .aspectFit)

        }




        print("Drawing icon")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

}
```

And finally in my viewcontroller

```
func configureCategoriesCells( cell: CategoriesTableViewCell, indexPath : IndexPath) {

    let categoryLabels = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
    let subCategoryLabels = ["subtitle","subtitle","subtitle,"subtitle", "subtitle", "subtitle"]

    cell.configure(forRow: indexPath.row, title: categoryLabels[indexPath.row], subTitle: subCategoryLabels[indexPath.row])
}
```

The result is the icons are drawn as required :)

let me know how you get on